# BUILD_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my react package.json file I am trying to set the build path to my node backend folder.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "BUILD_PATH=../server/public react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

But getting error

[image]

Comment: Please don't leave pictures of text in your question. For many users they will not be accessible and future people will not be able to find your question by searching so will not benefit from any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found any problem with BUILD_PATH. But I have solved it anyway by using **postbuild** script.

For windows

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"postbuild": "move build ../server/public",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

For linux-based system:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"postbuild": "mv build ../server/public",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

**postbuild** that does something after the build and will be called by npm/Yarn automatically.